# Como hacer un Guardar Como, para que el usuario seleccione la ruta?

Tags: c#

Buenos días estoy utilizando el  algoritmo que muestro más abajo, el cual me obtiene unos valores y me los inyecta en una carta de Word y hace que se generé un documento nuevo, luego ese documento se guarda en una ruta que yo definí y el código me quedo de la siguiente manera:   (Me gustaría poder hacer que el usuario defina donde quiere guardar el documento que se generá, algo como un guardar Como). Muchas gracias

```
                document.SaveAs2(FileName: @"C:\Users\jtaboga\Desktop\" + CEDULA + ".docx");

                document.Close();
                application.Quit();







    public static void GenerarCartaPreAdjudicacionPevi(DataTable[] datosCapturados)
    {



        int cantSelReg = datosCapturados.Length -1 ; //Cuenta la cantidad de registros que hay seleccionados
        int cantMinReg = 0; //Contador para poder recorrer los registros seleccionados


        while (cantMinReg <= cantSelReg)
        {

            foreach (DataRow Registro in datosCapturados[cantMinReg].Rows)
            {
                //prueba[0].Rows.Add(fila["VLR_SOL"]);
                string NOMEPL = (Registro["NOM_EPL"].ToString());
                string APEEPL = (Registro["APE_EPL"].ToString());
                string VLRAPR = (Registro["VLR_APR"].ToString());
                string CEDULA = (Registro["CEDULA"].ToString());
                string NOMPRO = (Registro["NOM_PRO"].ToString());

                var application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
                var document = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();

                document = application.Documents.Add(Template: @"D:\Proyectos\chc_deuda\resources\Document\cartaPreadj.docx");

                application.Visible = false;

                foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Field field in document.Fields)
                {
                    if (field.Code.Text.Contains("NOMEPL"))
                    {
                        field.Select();
                        application.Selection.TypeText(NOMEPL);
                    }
                    else if (field.Code.Text.Contains("APEEPL"))
                    {
                        field.Select();
                        application.Selection.TypeText(APEEPL);
                    }

                    else if (field.Code.Text.Contains("VLRAPR"))
                    {
                        field.Select();
                        application.Selection.TypeText(VLRAPR);

                    }

                    else if (field.Code.Text.Contains("NOMPRO"))
                    {
                        field.Select();
                        application.Selection.TypeText(NOMPRO);

                    }


                }




                document.SaveAs2(FileName: @"C:\Users\jtaboga\Desktop\" + CEDULA + ".docx");

                document.Close();
                application.Quit();



            }


            cantMinReg++;
        }



    }
```

Comment: Te refieres a un [SaveFileDialog](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-save-files-using-the-savefiledialog-component)?

Comment: Estaba mirando ese SaveFileDialog, pero no se como llevar esto a SaveFileDialog.             document.SaveAs2(FileName: @"C:\Users\jtaboga\Desktop\" + CEDULA + ".docx");

                document.Close();
                application.Quit();

Comment: Mira el enlace que te he puesto. Ahí tienes un ejemplo muy sencillo de como usar SaveFileDialog. Si el problema es que lo que quieres seleccionar es solo la carpeta y crear tu el nombre del archivo, usa [FolderBrowserDialog](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-choose-folders-with-the-windows-forms-folderbrowserdialog-component)